# Range startContainer isn't the deepest node

Tags: javascript, range, nodes, getselection

I want to generate an array of nodes in a page, which will have all of the possible startContainers for Ranges.

I've tried to use a treeWalker but it gives me a node which is deeper than the actual startContainer node, for example:

```
<p>For those keeping count at home, by the way, the <a target="_blank" href="http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/windows/apps/br229516.aspx">Windows 8 Developer Preview site</a> still happily talks about "Metro style app development,"; even though <a target="_blank" href="http://www.istartedsomething.com/20120816/microsofts-new-rule-no-metro-named-apps/">rumor has it</a> that Microsoft is now banning all apps with the word "Metro" in their name from the Windows Store.</p>
```

(Taken from techcrunch.com)

So my tree walker returns the following:

```
['For those keeping count at home, by the way, the ','Windows 8 Developer Preview site',' still happily talks about "Metro style app development,"; even though ','rumor has it',' that Microsoft is now banning all apps with the word "Metro" in their name from the Windows Store.']
```

(Split)

But when I try and get the following:
window.getSelection().getRangeAt(0).startContainer.textContent
I get:

```
['For those keeping count at home, by the way, the Windows 8 Developer Preview site still happily talks about "Metro style app development,"; even though rumor has it that Microsoft is now banning all apps with the word "Metro" in their name from the Windows Store.']
```

(Not split)

**Why isn't the startContainer more deep (split)? like the treeWalker is?**

Here is the code of the tree walker:

```
var walker = document.createTreeWalker(document.body, NodeFilter.SHOW_ALL, function(node) {
    if (node.nodeType == 3) {
        return NodeFilter.FILTER_ACCEPT;
    } else if (node.offsetWidth && node.offsetHeight) {
        return NodeFilter.FILTER_SKIP;
    } else {
        return NodeFilter.FILTER_REJECT;
    }
}, false);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I imagine you've selected the whole of an element, such as one of the links. The crucial fact is that the `startContainer` of a range obtained from the selection is not guaranteed to be a text node.

If a whole element is selected, some browsers will report the selection as spanning the children of the element's parent node. For a selection spanning one of a number of consecutive images, for example, it's essential. Imagine the selection encompasses just the second image in the HTML below:

```
<div><img src="1.jpg"><img src="2.jpg"><img src="3.jpg"></div>
```

In this case the selected range will have `startContainer` and `endContainer` properties that refer to the `<div>` element and `startOffset` 1 and `endOffset` 2, representing the range stretching between the children at indexes 1 and 2 in the container's `childNodes` property.

Comment: I've tried to select: "Windows Store.", why doesn't it return (for the startContainer.textContent): " that Microsoft is now banning all apps with the word "Metro" in their name from the Windows Store." ?

Comment: That sounds bizarre and wrong. I don't see that in this example: http://jsfiddle.net/DuFhf/

Comment: Sorry, my bad, I had cloned the range and changed the DOM - that is what made the cloned range go bizarre, thanks for the extra info on ranges!